# Finding the generalized tangent line at singular point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

I have the curve $x^3 + y^3 -3xy = 0$ . I need to find the singular points and find the generalized tangent lines at every singular point. And also give their equations as projective lines.

I can't find how to find the tangent lines at a singular point. So far i think that the only singular point is $(0,0)$.

Any tips and methods?

Comment: Do you mean [tangent cone at the origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_cone#Definition_in_algebraic_geometry)? It's given by the lowest degree term $-3xy$, so the two tangents are $x=0$ and $y=0$.

Comment: Yes! Thank you!